# Accessing DataConnectionTracker methods in Android 2.2

Tags: java, android, mobile, reflection

To enable mobile data connection for Android 2.3+ I currently use the following code:

```
Method setMobileDataEnabled = ConnectivityManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", boolean.class);
setMobileDataEnabled.setAccessible(true);
setMobileDataEnabled.invoke(connectivityManager, true);
```

This does not work for Android 2.2 and earlier however. My research told me that it can be achieved via the `DataConnectionTracker` (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/com/android/internal/telephony/DataConnectionTracker.java#DataConnectionTracker.setDataEnabled%28boolean%29) - but I have no idea how.

Can someone tell me in detail how to get access (via reflection?) to the `getDataEnabled()` and `setDataEnabled()` methods.